# Performance problems temporarily fixed by sp_updatestats, despite daily sp_updatestats execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I see a similar question here from 2013, but it was not answered so I am posting my version.

We are using SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64) and have a database that is about 70GB in size with about 350 tables.  On a daily basis, there are only a small number of updates occurring, though a couple times a year we dump a fair amount of data into it.  There are several Windows Services that constantly query the database, but rarely updated it.  There are also several websites that use it, and desktop applications (again, minimal daily updates).

The problem we have is that every once in a while a query that hits certain records will take much longer than normal. The following is a bogus example:

This query against 2 tables with less than 600 total records might take 30+ seconds:

```
select * 
from our_program_access bpa
join our_user u on u.user_id = bpa.user_id
where u.user_id = 50 and program_name = 'SomeApp'
```

But when you change the user_id value to another user record, it takes less than one second:

```
select * 
from our_program_access bpa
join our_user u on u.user_id = bpa.user_id
where u.user_id = 51 and program_name = 'SomeApp'
```

The real queries that are being used are a little more complex, but the idea is the same: search ID 50 takes 30+ seconds, search ID 51 takes < 1 second, but both return only 1 record out of about 600 total.

We have found that the issue seems related to the statistics.  When this problem occurs, we run sp_updatestats, and all the queries are equal and fast in time.  So, we started to run sp_updatestats in a maintainenance plan every night.  But the problem still pops up.  We also tried setting `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` on, but the problem eventually popped up.

While the database is large, it doesn't really undergo tremendous changes, though it does face constant queries from different services.

There are several other databases on the same server such as a mail log, SharePoint, and web filtering.  Overall, performance is very good until we run into this problem.

Does it make sense that on a database that undergoes relatively small changes daily would need to run sp_updatstats so frequently?  What else can we do to resolve this issue?

Comment: sp_updatestats invalidates cached plans so parameter sniffing is a possible cause

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had researched this, but since the query involved did not use a stored procedure I discounted it.  Are you saying that stored procedure parameter sniffing will affect performance of queries that don't use the stored procedure?  If that's the case, we're still in a bind unless we rewrite all our stored procedures, the code that use them, and/or rewrite all our queries across various platforms.  I just have a mental hurdle accepting 30+ seconds for selecting from a 600-record table join might be considered normal or by-design in any circumstance.